# Service principal credentials, set custom identifier?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, service-principal

We are linking personal developers certificates to a certain service principal. 
When a developer will leave our team, we will remove that credential from the service principal.

This works perfectly, but it's kind of a hassle because the name of the developer is not linked to the credentials.

I have noticed that their is a customIdentifierKey property on the credentials... but I cannot find how to set the customIdentifierKey.

Anyone knows how to do this?

```
New-AzureRmADAppCredential -ApplicationId $appId -CertValue $keyValue -EndDate $cert.NotAfter -StartDate $cert.NotBefore
```

Comment: Excuse me, has my answer been helpful? Or did it not solve your problem? If it did, could you mark it as answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Azure AD v2 cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0) to set and get custom key identifiers.

Here I am adding a certificate:

```
New-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential -ObjectId 2648416a-aaaa-4bc0-9190-aaaab6165710 -CustomKeyIdentifier 'Your key name' -StartDate '2017/06/01' -EndDate '2018/06/01' -Type AsymmetricX509Cert -Usage Verify -Value $keyValue
```

Assuming your `$keyValue` contains an X509 certificate. If it is a symmetric key, you can use `Symmetric` as the Type.

The custom key identifier is stored as bytes, encoded in ASCII.

So when you get one, you need to run it through a decode:

```
$cred = Get-AzureADApplicationKeyCredential -ObjectId 2648416a-aaaa-4bc0-9190-aaaab6165710
[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($cred.CustomKeyIdentifier)
```

Interestingly, if you set an identifier on a `PasswordCredential` (client secret) through Azure Portal, it encodes it in Unicode.